I’m dealing with an error when I run server in Django
PS C:\Users\besho\OneDrive\Desktop\DjangoCrushcourse> python manage.py runserver
C:\Users\besho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\besho\OneDrive\Desktop\DjangoCrushcourse\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\besho\OneDrive\Desktop\DjangoCrushcourse>
So I created a django file called lecture3 and an app called hello but when I start run server it shows me this error

It looks like the file manage,py does not exist at that location. Did you check it?

I don’t know how to check it

Look in your file explorer, there should be a file called manage.py somewhere. If there's not then you need to create a new Django app, if you're not sure how to do that follow the official Django tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial01/

If you ever receive a No such file or directory error then you need to be able to check that the file or directory exists in your file system.

You probably didn't create your Django project correctly. To create your Django project, from the command line, cd into a directory where you’d like to store your code, then run the following command:
django-admin startproject mysite .

Where mysite is the name of your project perhaps lecture3 in your case. This would automatically create your manage.py file. To create an app, make sure you’re in the same directory as manage.py and type this command:
python manage.py startapp myapp

Where myapp is your app name. It is recommended to do all these in a virtual environment.
See the official Django tutorial.
